# two ubuntu 14.04 operating systems along with windows 7

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uninstall

i have some really serious issue with my laptop.  this is regarding the Ubuntu 14.04 operation system. Presently,i have installed two ubuntu 14.04 's along side windows 7.
so , please can anyone tell me how to delete/remove one of the ubuntu 14.04??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single hard-disk with an extra Ubuntu installation, just boot from the one you want to keep, install gparted (`sudo apt-get gparted`). In gparted remove the unwanted partition and decide what to do with the empty space. Then, BEFORE REBOOTING type `sudo apt-get install /dev/sda` assuming /dev/sda is your hard disk. Reboot and you're done.